# Ansible is truncating strings longer than 4096 characters given to prompt

Tags: ansible

I want to pass a string longer than 4096 characters to prompt module from Ansible but it seems it will be truncated to only 4096 characters.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to me an ansible prompt module limitation, rather a `tty` limitation.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved with this http://blog.chaitanya.im/4096-limit

Comment: @AstinGengo then please post that as an answer (and accept it, if that's possible), so others can know you found a fix